# Why does `thread::JoinHandle<T>` have a type parameter?

Tags: multithreading, syntax, rust

In Rust, the `thread::JoinHandle<T>` type included with the standard library has the type parameter `T`. However, it doesn't seem that `T` is actually set or used for anything.

Indeed, [Rust's own documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) mostly just uses `thread::JoinHandle<_>` whenever it needs to assign a `JoinHandle<T>` to something. What does this `T` actually do?

Comment: *it doesn't seem that T is actually set or used for anything* — what do you think `pub fn join(self) -> Result<T>` is using then?

Comment: Therein lies the missing link. I didn't realize a thread-moved closure could actually return a value, as this fact is not particularly emphasized in the Rust documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the type that's returned from the threaded code. You can always auto-deduce the type, and you generally don't want to write the type explicitly. There's a few examples in the documentation for `join`, which returns a `Result<T>`.

The following example is from the documentation:

`spawn` returns a JoinHandle, which when joined returns the Result.

```
let computation = thread::spawn(|| { 
    // Some expensive computation.
    42
});
let result = computation.join().unwrap();
println!("{}", result);
```